# Python loadtxt does not read all lines in a file

Tags: python, numpy

I have several `.txt` files structured as follows (I only displayed header + 2 first lines for sake of clarity but it is actually composed of 42 lines):

t,theta
0.50000000000000000       0.27978056254513545       0.28056531081976965       0.28184349796989050       0.28362476472143522       0.28529900003685615       0.28683367227476964       0.28823455301836021       0.29181921292012614       0.29568335432374343       0.25080727396922869       0.22635724916100552       0.16562031409624156       0.16271839348554473       0.16300229100139449       0.16330739525510518       0.16415283457838703       0.14945459268320979       0.15101258182566338       0.14706028808113963       0.14868345762022553       0.15125285988273032       0.15533007739934029       0.16072140995546555       0.16849122831551247       0.19361662130028975
1.0000000000000000       0.27775510868111208       0.27885757469131578       0.28033431176905077       0.28198351682638784       0.28350962425864235       0.28494109796022915       0.28628597373302911       0.28966518035080507       0.29378238839419951       0.25059035964399212       0.23206540099345452       0.16647540522303941       0.16271695894834662       0.16299848480782447       0.16330417092260341       0.16415029228233191       0.14945173760682864       0.15101386572645115       0.14705491266349652       0.14868227639059581       0.15125244050535869       0.15532985040461164       0.16072125135581131       0.16849108903268453       0.19361676296090399

I use `np.loadtxt` to read these files with the following method:

```py
def read_theta_fromtxt(self):
    """Fills a trajectory instance from a variable read from txt file (path stored in pathname dict).
        
    --RETURN--
    time (1d-array, float64) : return time indexes corresponding to variables to be extracted
    var (2d-array, float64)  : extracted variable time serie. Can be 1d if deterministic or 2d if ensemble variable
                                   Dimension is (time serie length, number of members)
    """

    data     = np.loadtxt(self.pathname[0],skiprows=1) 
    time     = np.asarray(data[:,0]) ## col 0 is time
    var      = np.empty((len(time),self.m))
    var[:,0] = np.asarray(data[:,1+self.cell])
        
    for mb in np.arange(1,self.m):
        print(f'Read theta for member',mb)
        data      = np.loadtxt(self.pathname[mb],skiprows=1) 
        var[:,mb] = np.asarray(data[:,1+self.cell])
            
    return time, var
```

I call this method for value of self.m around 100 but I end up with the following error:

> `var[:,mb] = np.asarray(data[:,1+self.cell])`
> `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (42)`

This means that a `.txt` file does not contain the same number of lines than the first one but I manually checked the size of the problematic file and it is ok! If I read this file from an external ipython, I get the write size.

Why `loadtxt` is not reading all the lines in the file ? This method is part of a much larger code that also calls a lot of shell subprocess. There may be a limitation in memory ? Any idea ?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Post the text.

Comment: I'd do a separate test loadtxt on the problem file.  Assuming it runs check the data.shape.  You have the files, we don't.